# Ter retorno de um WindowsServices através de uma aplicação ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-service

Tenho um `Windows Service` que em determinado horário faz uma varredura na maquina e realiza um backup, para uma pasta em um servidor na rede.

O Serviço está rodando nas maquinas perfeitamente e, executando os backups sem erros.

Porém quero criar uma aplicação **WEB**, que recebesse as informações desta APP `Windows Service` como "Backup Realizado com Sucesso" dentre outras.

Como faço isso ? Através de um `ASP.NET WEB API` ? Alguma outra Forma ?

Comment: Você precisa mostrar o status do que está acontecendo no serviço? Precisa guardar o histórico do que foi executado para log?

Comment: @Intruso   Olha, não tinha pensado no Status do serviço. Mas é uma boa. Os Logs sim, penso em guardar. O que preciso inicialmente é saber como fazer isso. Pelo que posso pesquisar. Inicialmente mostrando o caminho, já seria uma excelente ajuda =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o **banco de dados** para guardar o status das execuções, servirá não só para mostrar ao usuário o que está acontecendo, mas, também o histórico de execução.

Crie uma Tabela (algo como **ProcessoExecucaoStatus**) onde você pode ter um campo Descrição e um outro Status (eu sempre tenho um campo ID que é chave primária com autoincremento, torna o controle muito objetivo e fácil de saber qual registro estou trabalhando).

O campo descrição pode ser texto para a descrever a rotina que foi executada e o campo status controla se foi executada ou não e se teve sucesso.

No service, altere o metodo que você executa diariamente (no nosso Exemplo, vamos chamar de RotinaDiariaBackup) para em cada fase do Método realizar a atualização de status no banco de dados.

Exemplo:

```
void RotinaDiariaBackup()
{
  try
    {
      rep.InsereStatusProcessoIniciado();

      this.ExecutaBackup(); //este metodo é a sua rotina (aquilo que o serviço ja executa de tempos em tempos.

      rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecutadoSucesso();
     }
  catch(Exception)
  {
     rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecucaoFalha();
  }
}
```

Logicamente, existem alguns pontos falhos nesse metodo, de diversos pontos de vista então tenha em mente o design da solução, não este código em si.

Você deve considerar melhor o tratamento de erros, considerar que os metodos que inserem no banco também podem falhar (deve-se ter um log de erros alternativo para rastreamento - um txt ou log do windows).

Mas, de forma geral, vamos explicar a lógica:

rep = repositório para acesso ao banco que guarda os dados de processo, para simplificar, não criei um objeto processoExecucao, mas, é altamente recomendado pois você pode precisar representar mais do que o status e descrição.

Logo, os metodos receberiam uma instância de **ProcessoExecucao** (que ainda não existe) para realizar as ações.

*rep.InsereStatusProcessoIniciado();* = basicamente este trecho insere no banco uma linha na tabela ProcessoExecucaoStatus com a descrição que você quiser como padrão e status (digamos que status = 0 seja execução em andamento).

*rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecutadoSucesso();* = Faz um update na linha que você inseriu agora atualizando o status da tabela para sucesso (digamos que seja Status = 1).

*rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecutadoFalha();* = Se um dos metodos anteriores falhar, uma exception será lançada e você atualiza o registro de status para 2 (status com erro).

Veja bem, deve-se atentar ao fato de que outros metodos podem falhar que não são sua rotina (o update de sucesso pode falhar), logo, você deve pensar em como controlar esse fluxo (transação?)

Terminadas as modificações no serviço, implemente uma tela que mostra os registros da tabela ProcessoExecucaoStatus e você terá o status do que foi executado e também do que estiver sendo executado, pois a tela só mostra os registros.

Essa abordagem de tabela de controle é bastante comum, porém, existem alguns problemas:

- o status da tabela não é o status do serviço, logo, se o serviço falhar por algum motivo que não seja a rotina, a tela não mostra isso.
- A tela mostra uma foto no tempo do que foi inserido, não há comunicação entre os processos, logo, ela não mostra o status do serviço naquele instante, mostra a ultima alteração de registro que foi possivel fazer, se você pretende usar a tela para monitorar o serviço, não é por esse caminho, vai ter que implementar uma outra forma de acesso ao serviço em si (o que geralmente é um pouco mais complexo).
- Performance do banco de dados, atualmente seu serviço não tem conexão com o banco de dados, realizando menos solicitações e como consequencia, o banco (que pode ser uma maquina simples) não sofre com isso, você estará indo no banco periodicamente (tanto para ler para a tela, quanto para executar suas rotinas).
- Faça o favor de não fazer um **Select * from ProcessoExecucaoStatus** na tela, coloque um condicional ou um top, com o tempo a tabela vai crescer. Isso se resolve sozinho que você implementa corretamente o repositório e acessa a tela das mesmas classes tratando o serviço como se fosse uma GUI, mas, nem todos pensam assim, muitos nem tem camadas ou tratam como outro mini-sistema.

Por fim, se você precisar incluir novas rotinas nessa sistemática, basta colocar uma coluna TipoRotina na tabela e criar um novo Metodo para a nova rotina, seguindo a mesma estrutura e a tela já irá refletir os novos status, fica fácil de dar manutenção e expandir, algo assim:

```
void RotinaDiariaEmails()
{
  try
    {
      int tipoRotina = 1; // 1 = envio diario de emails  - 0 = backup

      rep.InsereStatusProcessoIniciado(tipoRotina);

      this.ExecutaEnvioEMails(); //este metodo é a sua rotina 

      rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecutadoSucesso(tipoRotina);
     }
  catch(Exception)
  {
     rep.InsereStatusProcessoExecucaoFalha(tipoRotina);
  }
}
```

No serviço, você chamaria os métodos em sequencia ou teria uma outra estrutura de fila que executa os metodos:

```
void StartSomeTimes()
{
    RotinaDiariaEmails();
    RotinaDiariaBackup();
}
```

Provavelmente você tem um timer no seu serviço que executa de tempos em tempos, você chamaria **StartSomeTimes** no corpo do método que é executado pelo timer.

Comment: Show!!!  Excelente resposta...

Comment: quando você diz: "se você pretende usar a tela para monitorar o serviço, não é por esse caminho, vai ter que implementar uma outra forma de acesso ao serviço em si (o que geralmente é um pouco mais complexo)." Seria uma aplicação com o uso de `Socket` ? Algo relacionado? Poderia dar uma dicar pra eu poder fazer uma pesquisa

Comment: Pode ser feito por um socket tcp sim, sem problema. O server ficaria escutando no serviço e a página dispararia um metodo de ping para pegar o status do serviço, a cada post da página, o status seria atualizado.

Comment: Que informação você quer saber do serviço via socket?

Comment: Na real, eu só quero saber qual é uma outra forma de implementar o acesso ao serviço. Aí usei o `socket` como exemplo, se seria uma outra forma.

Comment: Velho, posso te indicar um tuto qualquer sobre sockets, mas, o que tu ta querendo é praticamente outra resposta :) dá uma olhada nesse tuto http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using (ingles) para a parte de tcp